# 端末上の emacs でマウス操作を受け付けることはできるか

Tags: emacs

http://mojavy.com/blog/2011/12/13/tmux_advent_calendar_2_2011/ を見ていました。
何かというと、 tmux 上でマウスクリックに対応する方法などが書いてありました。

端末 (とそれに接続されて走っているプログラム) でも、マウス操作を受け付けることができるのだと理解したのですが、emacs にこのような機能はありますか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(xterm-mouse-mode)` が自分のほしかったものっぽいです。